# ReactJS: searching through items in Home component (parent) with Search component (child)

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: Home (parent) and Search (child). Search is a collapsible window that is supposed to search through the data (items) displayed in Home, using user input (selected category of item and distance to item). I managed to get the search function to work, but there are a few issues that I don't know how to solve.

1. The search function works only once (it filters through items, then I have to reload page to filter again).
2. The search function is only passing categories, and not distance. So the Home shows results only based on selected categories but not location/distance to item.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Here's the Home function:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [categoriesSelected, setCategoriesSelected] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
 

  // Fetching all items

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/api/item-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAllData(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);

  // Fetching data of selected categories

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `URL/api/item-categories-list/?categories=${categoriesSelected}`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAllData(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, [categoriesSelected]);




  const handleSearch = (categoriesSelected, distance) => {
    setCategoriesSelected(categoriesSelected);
    setDistance(distance);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Search onSearch={handleSearch} />
      <div>
        {allData.map((post) => {
         //here I'm displaying the data
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and the Search component:

```
const Search = ({ onSearch }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categoriesSelected, setCategoriesSelected] = useState([]); // state() that stores the categories selected by the user to do the query
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]); //state() that stores the choices of categories available in the backend
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); //state() that stores the backend response with the requested data
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
  const [lng, setLng] = useState("");
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(1000);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/api/get-categories/")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);


  async function submitSearch(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response1 = await fetch(
        `https://URL/api/item-categories-list/?categories=${categoriesSelected}`
      );
      const response2 = await fetch(
        `https://URL/api/item-list-distance/?distance=${distance}&lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`
      );
      const data1 = await response1.json();
      const data2 = await response2.json();
      const filteredPosts = data1.filter((post1) => {
        return data2.some((post2) => post1.id === post2.id);
      });
      setPosts(filteredPosts);
      onSearch(categoriesSelected, distance);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }


 

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Search bar */}
      <Card>
       
      </Card>

      
        <Card >
          <div>
            <Box >
              <FormControl onSubmit={submitSearch}>
                {/* Categories dropdown */}

{/* Location */}
                <Location setLat={setLat} setLng={setLng} lat={lat} lng={lng} />

                {/* Distance dropdown */}



                <Button  type="submit"
                  onClick={submitSearch}
                >
                  Search
                </Button>
              </FormControl>
            </Box>
          </div>

        </Card>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Proposal

```
onSearch(categoriesSelected, distance);
```

I believe you want to show the filtered posts in the Home View. However the Search function only passes the selected categories back to Home, which is why the distance is not considered in the displayed results.

Alternatively, fetching the posts matching searches from the Search and passing that result to Home might fix the view and also help you completely eliminate the second effect to fetch of data for Selected Categories. The second effect in home is also fired on mount after your first hook so that may not be what you are looking for.

```
onSearch(filteredPosts, distance); // passing filtered posts instead
```

I'm not sure why a reload is needed after you search once. It could be because the Home > `categoriesSelected` valued does not change in Effect hook and so the effect is not fired but simplifying your code as mentioned above might help fix this issue.

## Possible Improvements

### Reduce API calls + Data payloads

I see you are making 2 calls to the backend to get all possible data you might need and filtering the results to show only relevant results (by category and distance).

Depending on the result set, this could result in a lot of work being done on the client side and it might be better to setup an endpoint ex `/search` on the backend that does the same filtering and  returns the relevant data in a request.

This would limit the work done on mobile devices which could have low computing power and reduce the amount data passed over the network, thereby reducing the impact on the customers data package and your own API costs.

### Monitor Errors

An alternative to logging errors to console could be to use a tool like [Sentry](https://youtu.be/sA1rED-zb6w) or [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/dg/real-user-monitoring/frontend-performance) to track your errors by release, URL, device or other metrics that can help you methodically improve your frontend and troubleshoot real world customer issues over time.

Comment: Thank you Larry! I think I found the culprit for the Search function only working once. There was an issue with the 'categoriesSelected' state variable in the Search component. In the 'handleCategoryChange' function it wasn't updating the state of categoriesSelected correctly, but overwriting the value with an array, where it should have been a string. Fixed it with: ```const handleCategoryChange = (selected) => {
    setCategoriesSelected(selected.join(","));
  }; ``` and passing this function to onSelect and onRemove in Multiselect component.

Comment: I agree that I should reduce the API calls and simplify the code. I will work on it, and research the tools you recommended! Thank you :)